# How do I resolve these unmet dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

Opening the Ubuntu software center yields an error that says:

```
Items cannot be installed or removed until the package catalog is repaired. Do you want to repair it now?
```

After clicking repair, the following error is returned:

```
Package dependencies cannot be resolved
```

After doing some research, many people suggest running:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

However, it returns:

```
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libnss3-1d: Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.16.3-1ubuntu1) but 3.15.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.3
 is installed
 libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (=2:3.16.3-1ubuntu1) but 3.15.4-0ubuntu0.12.04.3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I have no idea where to go from here. If I recall correctly, I was trying to install a flash plug in for Firefox, because youtube was occasionally throwing me an error and telling me to upgrade flash player.

This error is especially frustrating, as I cannot install software until it is resolved. It is worth noting that I have also tried using Synaptic Package Manager's "fix broken dependencies" or whatever, and it didn't work.

Comment: I've read that document and tried the first method, to no avail. If I have to purge a ppa, I do not know which one and do not want to risk removing something vital.

Comment: The problematic packages appear to be Network Security Security libraries - shared databases and Network Security Service Libraries - Transitional Package. This can be found under Ubuntu Software Center > Installed > Unknown

Comment: I've tried everything in "How do I resolve unmet dependencies?" The solution does not work for me. This is not a duplicate.

Comment: Without lots of details about exactly what you have tried and what happened, it's still somewhat unlikely this could be helpfully answered beyond referring you to [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). So you may wish to [edit] this to add the details about the many attempted solutions you've tried, how you applied them, what happened, and anything else that you think may be relevant.

Comment: I just need some help learning to diagnose the problem myself. All I know to explain is that when I was using youtube on chromium, I was told I needed to update my flash plugin. I attempted to install the newest plugin, and afterwards I started receiving this error message. Where do I even begin?

Comment: I solved this problem on my own. I assure you it was not a duplicate question. I'm wondering if you guys even read the damn thing.